# how to get the status of the particular process by the shell_exec()?

Tags: php

I want to know the status of the process by passing the name in the command and execute it with the function shell_exec().

I have tried this:

```
` 
  $checkProcessStatus = "ps aux | grep <ProcessName>";
  $status = shell_exec($checkProcessStatus);
  dd($status);
`
```

I got this result:

```
`
 user 17072  0.0  0.2 166216 33332 pts/3    S+   11:31   0:00 <ProcessName> artis
 user 20397  0.0  0.0  14232   868 pts/3    S+   11:52   0:00 grep <ProcessName>
`
```

I want only the Status Like "Running" OR "Sleeping".

Comment: you can explode $status
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php


then check Status value,


if (strpos($statusValue, 'R') === 0 || strpos($statusValue, 'S') === 0) {
    //is R or S status
}

Comment: @VasiliyLetuyev, after exploding the text which index to be check with 'R' OR 'S' ?

Comment: i wrote answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
<?php
$command = 'ps aux';
$result = shell_exec($command);
//split for rows
$processes = explode("\n", $result);
//delete head row
array_shift($processes);
//analyze
foreach ($processes as $rawProcess) {
    //beware, command line column may include spaces, that why last group is (.+)
    preg_match('/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.+)/', $rawProcess,$matches);
    //preg match doesn't find anything
    if (empty($matches)) {
        continue;
    }
    //is sleeping status
    if (strpos($matches[8], 'S') === 0) {
        echo $rawProcess;
        echo "\n";
        continue;
    }
    //is running status
    if (strpos($matches[8], 'R') === 0) {
        echo $rawProcess;
        echo "\n";
        continue;
    }
    //is not sleeping and not running status
}
```

You can use $matches[N] for any column.

By the way you can use awk to grep data by status

```
ps aux | awk 'substr($8,1,1) == "S" || substr($8,1,1) == "R"'
```

P.S.

Status mean:

```
D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
R    running or runnable (on run queue)
S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
T    stopped by job control signal
t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
X    dead (should never be seen)
Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent
```

Status addition mean

```
<    high-priority (not nice to other users)
N    low-priority (nice to other users)
L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
s    is a session leader
l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
+    is in the foreground process group
```